# Why can I receive Data from my WebApi over a normal Browser but not over WPF Client?

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api

This is my first question hear, so please be patient.

At first let me describe my problem.

I have written a small Service with Web-Api to access Data from a Database.
The Web Api runs on an IIS 7 in our corporate network.

Now if i send a request to this API with a normal browser like Chrome i get a correct answer without any problems.
But if a want to send this request through my .NET WPF-Client i face several problems.

- Problem 1:
  I have to specify a proxy for the HttpClient
- Problem 2:
  When I try to connect without a proxy I get a this Exception:

> `

```
"System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException" wurde aufgefangen.
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at m.KEB_FUP.Daten.DbAbfragen.<GetUnversionedListeOfDocuments>d__1.MoveNext() in c:\Bosch\m.KEB-FUP\dev\src\cs\m.KEB-FUP\Daten\DbAbfragen.cs:line 53
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at m.KEB_FUP.Seiten.Sachnummern.SachnummernUCModel.<SucheSachnummer>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\Bosch\m.KEB-FUP\dev\src\cs\m.KEB-FUP\Seiten\Sachnummern\SachnummernUCModel.cs:line 13
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at m.KEB_FUP.Seiten.Sachnummern.SachnummernUC.<txtBxSuchSachnummer_KeyDown>d__1.MoveNext() in c:\Bosch\m.KEB-FUP\dev\src\cs\m.KEB-FUP\Seiten\Sachnummern\SachnummernUC.xaml.cs:line 64
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=Unable to connect to the remote server
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
       InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
            HResult=-2147467259
            Message=A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.3.37:50224
            Source=System
            ErrorCode=10060
            NativeErrorCode=10060
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                 at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
            InnerException:
```

`

- Problem 3:
  I always get StatusCode 401 'Unauthorized' as an answer in my .NET client when proxy is set

**So here my question:
Why is it possible to retrieve data over a Browser but not through my .NET Client using HttpClient?**

Hear the code I use in the client.

```
static class DbAbfragen
{
    private static HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        var proxy = new WebProxy("http://localhost:8080", false);
        proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
                                        {
                                            Proxy = proxy,
                                            UseProxy = true,
                                            UseDefaultCredentials = true
                                        };

        var client = new HttpClient(handler);

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://win7:50224/KebFupWeb/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0); // Timeout = 5 Minuten

        return client;
    }


    public async static Task<IEnumerable<object>> GetUnversionedListeOfDocuments(string sachnummer = "")
    {
        IEnumerable<object> retVal = new List<object>();

        var client = DbAbfragen.GetHttpClient();

        var result = await client.GetAsync("list/unversioned/username/partno");

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var docList = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<object>>();

            if (docList.Count() >= 0)
            {
                retVal = docList;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException(result.ToString());
        }

        return retVal;
    }

}
```

And here is the error im facing:

> `StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content:             System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
>   {
>     MS-Author-Via: DAV
>     DAV: 1,2,<http://www.oracle.com/xdb/webdav/props>
>     Date: Wed, 18 Nov 2015 12:17:17 GMT
>     Server: Oracle
>     Server: XML
>     Server: DB/Oracle
>     Server: Database
>     WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="XDB"
>     Content-Length: 147
>     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   }`

Comment: `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="XDB"` seems wrong. Should have been some base64 encoded string if you're using `Basic` authentication scheme.

Comment: After adding this line `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("")));` I get a BadRequest as answer

Comment: Pass the actual credentials

Comment: Adding `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password")));` brings back the unauthorized error. And in a normaler Browser like Chorme it works perfectly. I don't get the reason why it works in chrome but not in my client.

Comment: Do you have control over the server?

Comment: Yes its a sever in our corporate network